# How add Google analytics plugin for phonegap 3.1.0?

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, phonegap-plugins

Is there a compatible GoogleAnalitycs plugin for phonegap 3.1.0?
Thank's!

Answer (score 4):

This one is working fine for me: https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin

I've used cli instead of plugman-installation:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin.git
```

Do not forget to add the trackPage() action as i did before...

Comment: Unfortunately this project is not very active.
It looks like support for Amazon FireOS waits for nearly one year to be merged into master brunch... :-(
https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin/pull/47

Answer (score 0):

I am using Dan Wilson's plugin.
https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin

You will need to setup a new Google Analytics "Mobile App" account. Beyond that the setup instructions on GitHub are pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Hi,I get analytics undefined when using it with sencha touch !

Comment: When do you see the error? Is it in the browser or after you build it with PhoneGap and install the app on a device?

Comment: @ram-mere the plugin only supports iOS and Android.